# Problema com caracteres especiais php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou usando php na pagina html para validar um formulario. Quando o banco retona o texto para a pagina o php não está exibindo o resultado com caracteres especiais.
Onde está o erro?

Pagina:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Tabela do banco MYSQL:

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

Resultado do `PHP`:

```
echo "<ul>";  
  echo "<li>";
    echo "<a data-toggle='modal' href='{$link}'>" ;
      echo "{$titulo} </a>- {$descricao}";
  echo "</li>";
  echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Tente utilizar "echo utf8_decode($variavel);"

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro vê se este arquivo está salvo também em UTF-8!

Comment: @fleuquerlima testei os 2 e não deu certo. Mais obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja no seu banco se está gravando corretamente as informações. Se sim, mude isso:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Para isso:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

O encode do seu banco deveria ser `latin1_swedish_ci`, pois aceita acentos, ç e todos caracteres latinos.

Ou ainda, tente:

```
 echo "utf8_decode({$titulo}) </a>- utf8_decode({$descricao})";
```

Comment: Usei a `meta` com `iso-8859-1` e deu certo, como tenho preferencia para `utf8`, voltei para ele e alterei o banco para `latin1_swedish_ci` e perfeito. Muito obrigado, sem sua ajuda iria me bater horas.